# MySQL INSERT-SELECT a non-mandatory field with JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, insert

I have a table (`netStream`), that has 2 foreign keys: (`logSessions_logSessionID`) and (`accountSessions_accountSessionID`).

The (`logSessions_logSessionID`) is mandatory the (`accountSessions_accountSessionID`) is NOT mandatory.

Here is the part of the block-scheme that shows the connections and the non-mandatory status:

[image]

(The background: `logSessions` are the sessions that every visitor have, `accountSessions` are the login sessions. Everybody has a `logSession` (since everybody is a visitor), but not everybody is logged in, so they do not have `accountSession`)

I want to insert a row into (`netStream`), in every case there is a (`logSession`), but it is not the same with (`accountSession`). So, when there is an (`accountSession`), I want to insert that ID too, if there is no (`accountSession`), then just leave that field in (`netStream`) NULL.

The hash values are stored in `Binary(x)`, this is why I use `UNHEX()`.

This is the MySQL I wrote, there is no error message, but it does not work. What is the problem?

```
INSERT INTO `test-db`.`netStream` (`netStreamHash`, `logSessions_logSessionID`, `accountSessions_accountSessionID`)
    SELECT UNHEX("1faab"), `logSessions`.`logSessionID`, NULL FROM `logSessions` CROSS JOIN `accountSessions`
        WHERE `logSessions`.`logSessionHash` = UNHEX("aac") AND 
        `accountSessions`.`accountSessionHash` = UNHEX("2fb");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If understand you correctly you are probably looking for something like this

```
INSERT INTO `test-db`.`netStream` (
    `netStreamHash`, 
    `logSessions_logSessionID`, 
    `accountSessions_accountSessionID`)
SELECT UNHEX("1faab"), 
       (SELECT `logSessionID` FROM `logSessions` 
        WHERE `logSessionHash` = UNHEX("aac")),
       (SELECT `accountSessionID` FROM `accountSessions` 
        WHERE `accountSessionHash` = UNHEX("2fb"));
```

*If there is no matching row in `accountSessions` then you'll get `NULL` inserted in `accountSessions_accountSessionID` in `netStream` table*

Comment: Thank you, that is working. I am wondering about the performance. Does two SELECT in one INSERT have the same performance as JOIN?

Comment: @ÁgotaHorváth You're welcome. In that particular case IMHO it has no performance implications. For data sets to be joined they have to be selected first anyway.